# Multiply the number based on its length

Tags: java

I wanted to multiply the number based on its String length.
For example

```
String s = "153";
```

So, here the length of the above string is 3. So i wanted to multiply each number in the string 3 times (which is the actual length of the string)

Something like below

```
Here the length is 3
Something like this 1*1*1+5*5*5+3*3*3
```

Can anyone please help me in that?

This is what I have tried:

```
int number = 153; 
String originalNumber = number+""; 
char[] ch = originalNumber.toCharArray();
int length = originalNumber.length();
for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) { 
  char c = ch[i]; 
  for (int j = 0; j < ch.length; j++) { 
     // I'm stuck here 
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to implement yourself those steps: First convert the string in an array of char, then for each element compute the result of the element multiplied by the the size of the array.

Comment: What have you tried already, where are your problems?

Comment: int number = 153;
  
  String originalNumber = number+"";
   char[] ch = originalNumber.toCharArray();
  int length = originalNumber.length();
  
  for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
   
   char c = ch[i];
   
   for (int j = 0; j < ch.length; j++) {
    // I'm stuck here
   }
  }

Comment: This is what i tried. Not sure how to proceed

Comment: And then? Do you want to add or multiply the results? So.. is it `1*1*1+5*5*5+3*3*3` or `1*1*1*5*5*5*3*3*3`?

Comment: I want to add like this 1*1*1+5*5*5+3*3*3

Comment: I've edited your attempt into the question. When asking questions here, it's important to show what you've tried. You can further [edit] your question if you have more details. Good luck!

Comment: So the result should be `"112527"`? You can use `String.charAt(i), Character.digit('3', 10)` and so on.

Comment: No, the result should be 1+125+27 = 153

Comment: You can still use `String.charAt` and `Character.digit` as @JoopEggen suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have to take each digit and take it to the power of the length of your string, then add all those results up.
You could do the following:

```
    String s = "153";
    int result = 0;

    for (char n : s.toCharArray())
        if (Character.isDigit(n))
            result += Math.pow(Character.getNumericValue(n), s.length());

    System.out.println(result);
```

It prints:

```
153
```

I added a safety check to see if the char is actually a digit (`if (Character.isDigit(n))`).

Answer (score 1):

1. Classic solution : You need to turn each char, in an `int` then use use power to the length and sum all :

   ```
   int res = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
       int newNb = (int) Math.pow(Character.digit(ch[i], 10), ch.length);
       res += newNb;
   }
   ```
2. `for-each loop` solution

   ```
   for (char c : ch) {
       int newNb = (int) Math.pow(c - '0', ch.length);
       res += newNb;
   }
   ```

---

To turn a `char c` to its corresponding `int` value you can do :

- `int a = Character.getNumericValue(c);`
- `int a = Character.digit(c, 10);`
- `int a = c - '0';`

Comment: or just `int a = c;` ;)

Comment: @mumpitz that's the point : NO ;) it'll use it's code point which is 61 ;) as ascii table says

Comment: Thats right. If you you are interested in the actual numeric value (which you'd be in this scenario), you should **not** do it this way. It turns the char into an int, but you get the codepoint. Sorry for just throwing that in without explanations, bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply iterate over each digit of the given string and calculate it's power. It is better to use `str.charAt(i)` instead of `str.toCharArray()` to not create additional `char[]`.

```
public static int multiplyNumberLength(String str) {
    int res = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
            res += Math.pow(str.charAt(i) - '0', str.length());

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn a character back into a digit:

```
char c = ch[i];
int digit = c - '0';
int product = 1;
```

then for your inner loop multiply the digit into the product.